# Error when running foreach with forecast

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, forecasting

I don´t know if this has anything to do with the foreach, but I guess more with the forecast...

Below is just a small example of bigger table, I want to run this script in parallel as it takes some time. I get the error message:

"Error in { : task 2 failed - "argument is of length zero"

and I don´t know why as the forecast function works fine when running separately.

```
# Test Data
Data <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(c("2017-01-01", "2017-02-01", "2017-03-01", "2017-04-01", "2017-05-01", "2017-06-01")),
               A    = c(1,6,3,6,5,6),
               B    = c(6,5,6,3,6,1))
Data <- as.xts(Data[-1], Data[,1]) #convert to xts for the forecast package                                      

library(foreach)
library(doSNOW)
library(forecast)
cl <- makeCluster(2, type="SOCK") # for 2 cores machine
registerDoSNOW (cl)

# forecast the values in each column and bind the result of the forecast together by column to get one data.frame
Result <- foreach(j = 1:ncol(Data), .combine = "cbind", .packages = "forecast") %dopar% {forecast(Data[,j], h = 6L)$mean}

stopCluster(cl)


# Result how it should look like
Result <- data.frame(A    = c(4.7,4.7,4.7,4.7,4.7,4.7),
                     B    = c(4.4,4.4,4.4,4.4,4.4,4.4))
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is stemming from the `xts` package not being exported.  The environments need access the `[` method for your `xts` object `Data`.

You can fix this using `.packages = c("forecast","xts")` (suggested) or by explicitly using `` xts:::`[.xts` `` (not suggested, but included for proof of why error is occuring).

Note: the output does not match the expected result posted in your question

```
library(foreach)
library(doSNOW)
library(forecast)

# Test Data
Data <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(c("2017-01-01", "2017-02-01", "2017-03-01", 
                                    "2017-04-01", "2017-05-01", "2017-06-01")),
                   A    = c(1,6,3,6,5,6),
                   B    = c(6,5,6,3,6,1))
Data <- xts::as.xts(Data[-1], Data[,1]) #convert to xts for the forecast package                                      

cl <- makeCluster(2, type="SOCK") # for 2 cores machine
registerDoSNOW(cl)

# forecast the values in each column and bind the result of the forecast together by column to get one data.frame
Result_export <- foreach(j = 1:ncol(Data), .combine = "cbind", 
                         .packages = c("forecast","xts")) %dopar% {
                           forecast(Data[,j], h = 6L)$mean
                           }

Result_colon  <- foreach(j = 1:ncol(Data), .combine = "cbind", 
                         .packages = c("forecast")) %dopar% {
                           forecast(xts:::`[.xts`(Data,j=j), h = 6L)$mean
                         }

identical(Result_export, Result_colon)
# [1] TRUE

as.data.frame(Result_export)
#   result.1 result.2
# 1 4.499867 4.500107
# 2 4.499867 4.500107
# 3 4.499867 4.500107
# 4 4.499867 4.500107
# 5 4.499867 4.500107
# 6 4.499867 4.500107

stopCluster(cl)
```